# Algorithm for fast vector-vector (a * a^H) multiplication?

Tags: algorithm, vector

The vector **a** containing complex numbers is of size N-by-1. The task is to find the matrix **A** (N-by-N) obtained by multiplication **a** * **a**^*H*, where *H* is the Hermitian operator (conjugate-transpose), so that matrix **A** is Hermitian.

Is there any algorithm to do this faster than O(N^2)? (except that only half the matrix can be computed). Can the divide and conquer approach be applied here somehow?

Comment: The result has `O(N^2)` entries, doesn't it? If so, I don't see how you can hope to compute it faster than in `O(N^2)` time.

Comment: @NPE Yes, matrix **A** has NxN entries. But there are some clever algorithms to speed-up multiplication. E.g. Karatsuba algorithm [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) to multiply two integers of Strassen algorithm [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) for fast multiplication of two square matrices. In our case we have a lot of extra information since we have only one vector. So, maybe something similar can be applied...

Comment: But you still have to *populate* the `O(N^2)` elements of `A`, don't you? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, but in algorithms mentioned above some of the matrix elements (which can be another matrix) can be computed though other previously computed elements. E.g. in Strassen algorithm one needs only 7 matrix multiplications and several summations instead of 8 matrix multiplications. This is done recursively, therefore improvement is huge for large matrices.

Comment: @NPE: write operations are may or may not be cheaper than arithmetic. So you have `O(N^2)` write operations, but can you have a sub-quadratic number of addition or multiplication operations?

Comment: @Oleg There can be no matrix multiplication algorithm that is faster than O(n^2) because the size of the output is O(n^2). In fact, both Karatsuba and Strassen which you mention are slower. For the same reason, this problem can't be solved in faster than O(n^2), no matter how fancy your algorithm is.

Comment: @Rhymoid No, you can't. The result contains up to n*(n+1)/2 different elements. Each one is the result of an arithmetic operation. So there must be at least that many operations.

Comment: I agree that you can't hope to compute `n^2` elements faster than `O(n^2)`.  But is `n` really that large that you need a faster algorithm?  Is this really a bottleneck in what you're trying to do?

Comment: It sounds like there are large coefficients on the lower order terms, so the point is to not have that on n^2.

Comment: @interjay "There can be no matrix multiplication algorithm that is faster than O(n^2) because the size of the output is O(n^2)". Is there any theorem proving that? "In fact, both Karatsuba and Strassen which you mention are slower". I still don't understand that... Karatsuba algorithm requires N^1.585 multiplications instead of N^2. Strassen requires N^2.8 operations accounting that to multiply matrices one needs in general N^3 operations. So both of them are faster than straight-forward "population" of the answer.

Comment: Do you need a theorem to prove that writing n^2 values takes O(n^2)? Assuming that in your model it takes O(1) to write each value and you can only write one value at a time, the result is obvious. I made a mistake mentioning Karatsuba above since it isn't a matrix multiplication algorithm. Normal multiplication output size is O(n) so any multiplication algorithm, including Karatsuba, can't be faster than O(n). Matrix multiplication output size is O(n^2) so matrix multiplication algorithms can't be faster than O(n^2). The fact that Strassen is faster than O(n^3) is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Okey, now I see your point. Thanks to everybody for discussion!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class with a `Matrix` interface which internally stores only the given vector `a` and does one complex multiplication on demand when a matrix element is accessed.

Depending on your use case, this could be more efficient, because it uses much less memory.

Comment: I agree, for some case it can be useful and memory efficient. But I need whole resulting matrix afterwards. And I have problem with computational time of this matrix, not with memory.

Comment: Why do you believe the computation of this matrix is the bottleneck? If you need the whole matrix in the following operation, this means this also requires at least O(n^2) operations.

Comment: I just have many of such calculations. But now I see where I was wrong. Thanks!